# SharePoint 2013 filter based on created date

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, calculated-column-formula

I am struggling to construct a SharePoint formula in which I want to show items within 14 days from created date.

> i.e. between created and created+14<=Today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within 14 days meaning:

```
Created is greater or equal to [Today]-14
```

**So try to adjust your filter as the following:**

[image]